# Where to keep configuration for SharePoint solution

Tags: 2010, development

Where do I store a configuration of a sharepoint solution? The solution has a feature activated on a site collection, so there will be multiple instances of it running on a farm. Installation and feature activation will be automated with powershell because the feature needs to be activated on multiple site collections. All the instances need the same set of configuration parameters, set of keys and values. Where do I store them? A file, registry or some other place? If if is a file, is it a good idea to store it in c:\ProgramData directory?

Each instance of the solution writes logs. Is it a good idea to store the log file at c:\ProgramData as well?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use your own folder, instead use SharePoint's 14 hive folder located at: `Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14`.

Comment: is it for one web application or for multiple applications?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE it is one application

Comment: If it is for one web applications then i would prefer to Bin directory of the Web app under the inet pub, becuase when you apply the upgrade/cu this directory will not effect

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Sorry, I might have been imprecise before. It is a one solution in a sense of one visual studio project, it has one feature. But this feature can be activated on different site collections belonging to different web apps. But all these instances need to use the same config. So it needs to be some common location for all the instances. Can you please advise something that suits this scenario?

Comment: check my answer, it will give you complete understanding and best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configuration settings** being used by more than one component are considered global settings. Examples of settings in this category are URLs for external Web services, business object settings, and data settings. These settings are best kept in **web.config** and managed as described in the "Have SharePoint Manage Custom Config Settings" section.

You can automate custom settings installation and management by using the SharePoint object model and deployment tools. Use the **SPWebConfigModification class**, solution deployment, and the CONFIG directory under the SharePoint 15 hive to form your configuration management strategy. Please see the "Build Deployable Solutions" section in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458798.aspx#id0090105) for additional details about deploying through solutions.

[SharePoint Configuration Options (Recommended)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855123(v=office.12).aspx#odcwss3_ManageCustConfigOptions_SharePtOptions)

Comment: web.config is different for each web application and questioner is looking for storing settings across web applications rather for a single web application.

Comment: I found an MSDN article that might be useful for someone in the future: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855123(v=office.12).aspx#odcwss3_ManageCustConfigOptions_SharePtOptions

Comment: I updated the answer with MSDN link. The blog i mentioned based on that MSDN article. :)